# При использовании вложенных запросов, SQL возвращает NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет. Есть следующий запрос к БД:

```
SELECT 
    u.id AS user_id, 
    u.firstname AS user_firstname, 
    u.lastname AS user_lastname,  
    ((SELECT SUM(`count`)
        FROM `user_balance`
        WHERE status= 2 AND user_id = 37
        )
        -
        (SELECT SUM(`count`)
        FROM `user_balance`
        WHERE status = 1 AND user_id = 37
        )
    ) AS result
FROM users AS u
WHERE u.id = 37
```

Для понимания картины: `status=2` - это пополнение счета, `status=1` - это списание средств.

Вопрос: если юзер пополнил счет, но еще не было ни одного списания, данный запрос возвращает NULL в столбце result. Как это пофиксить? Самый простой вариант (он же костыль) - это с регой пользователя вставлять сразу 2 строки, чтобы результатом данных запросов был не NULL. Какие есть еще варианты, более правильные?

Answer (score 3):

Нужно применить функцию `IFNULL` и запрос переписать так:

```
SELECT 
    u.id AS user_id, 
    u.firstname AS user_firstname, 
    u.lastname AS user_lastname,  
    ((SELECT SUM(`count`)
        FROM `user_balance`
        WHERE status= 2 AND user_id = 37
        )
        -
        (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`count`),0)
        FROM `user_balance`
        WHERE status = 1 AND user_id = 37
        )
    ) AS result
FROM users AS u
WHERE u.id = 37
```

Comment: Раз уж стандарт предусматривает функцию `COALESCE`, а сервер ее поддерживает, то лучше использовать ее, ИМХО.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    u.id AS user_id, 
    u.firstname AS user_firstname, 
    u.lastname AS user_lastname,  
    (SELECT SUM(case status when 2 then `count`
        when 1 then -`count` end)
        FROM `user_balance`
        WHERE user_id = u.id
     ) AS result
FROM users AS u
WHERE u.id = 37
```